# Rotate an element on the Y axis

Tags: css, css-animations

I setup a simple **keyframe animation to rotate an element on the Y axis** but it is choppy, am I missing a property?

```css
.circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  animation: rotateY 1s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateY {
  0% { transform: rotateY( 60deg); }
  20% { transform: rotateY( 120deg); }
  40% { transform: rotateY( 180deg); }
  60% { transform: rotateY( 240deg); }
  80% { transform: rotateY( 300deg); }
  100% { transform: rotateY( 360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The "choppy" effect is created because of the default [animation-timing-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function) (ease), you should set it to `linear`.

Also there is no point in specifying states at 20%, 40%... for the keyframe animation, you can just specify the end state with the "to" keyword :

```css
.circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  animation: rotateY 1s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes rotateY {
  to { transform: rotateY(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

*Note that you also need to use vendor prefixes depending on the browsers you want to support. See [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=css-animation) for more info.*

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I didn't know you could use "to" in a keyframe! Edit - SO's snippet does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean it to be like this?

```css
.circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  animation: rotateY 1s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateY {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

The changes there are to add a timing function that's linear (rather than an ease), and to make the animation a little clearer as to what's going on.

Comment: Linear works, but it seems to rotate imperfectly after it has gone through the keyframe.